# SQL Server back-end with MS Access 2007 front end. Number of users

Tags: ms-access, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a `.mdb` MS Access 2007 which is connected to a SQL Server backend. The tables are linked using a system DSN.

I need to do a stress test on the system and I would like to know the maximum number of users who can use the system at the same time.

The access `.mdb` file is done through the WTS.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The max number of users is going to depend on how well the application is written, and how good the network each user has.

You might have a great application, but if they are connecting to SQL server over a slow network, then the application will be slow with 2 users, and will be slow with 250 users.

If the network is good, and the application is well written to respect bandwidth requirements, then the application will likely run the SAME speed with 2, 10, 20 or 100 users.

And deepening on how large and powerful the SQL server box is? Then you can easy scale out to 500 users at the same time.

So this question is much difficult to answer. The network from the Access application to the SQL server is an important factor.

And some applications perform poorly with 5 users and SQL server, and thus such applications will perform even WORSE with 100, or 200 users.

So how well does the application work with 5 users, and then with say 25. If it written well, you likely not notice the difference. On the other hand if it slow with 1 user, then you downhill all the way from that point on as you add more users.

So it better run REALLY well with one user if you planning to scale out to many users.

So it certainly possible to have a 1000 users at the same time without much effort. As noted this depends on how well the application was designed with SQL in mind. So the quality of the work the developers done will be the LARGEST factor in how many users you can scale out to. As noted the capacity of the server and SQL will also determine the max number of users.

With a typical application that respects SQL server, then running 50 or 100 users should hardly break SQL server into a sweat is should be easy obtainable.

In fact for those 50 users, your HUGE resource HOG will be WTS.

Assuming you mean windows terminal services, then that setup requires HUGE resources, and far more then your SQL server will. This system will require much more attention and resources then SQL server. As noted, if the application runs rather well with 1-2 users, then usually such applications will run easy with 25. If the application runs slow with only 1 or 2 users, then you going to have scaling problems as you add more users.

At the end of the day, there are FAR FAR too many factors to give an answer without a case by case knowledge of the server involved, the network bandwidth, the capacity of the WTS, and MOST important how well the application was designed (this factor is #1).